# Taylor expansion of complicated integral expression

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion

I have the following function

$$
L(T) = N \frac{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}ye^{- v(y)/kT}\text{d}y}{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{- v(y)/kT}\text{d}y}
$$

where

$$
v(y) = \frac{k_0}{2}(y-a)^2-\gamma (y-a)^3
$$

with $\gamma > 0$

I am supposed to approximate this using a Taylor series expansion to first order in $\gamma$, which I think means that I expand around $y=\gamma$. I am supposed to end up with

$$
L(T) \approx N \left[a + \frac{3\gamma kT }{ k_0^2}\right]
$$

Setting $f(y)= \frac{L(T)}{N}$, I get that

$$
f(y) = \frac{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} ye^{-\frac{k_0 }{2kT} (y-a)^2 + \frac{\gamma}{kT}(y-a)^3}\text{d}y}{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{k_0 }{2kT} (y-a)^2 + \frac{\gamma}{kT}(y-a)^3}\text{d}y}
$$

The first order Taylor series expansion will be

$$
f(y) \approx f(\gamma) + \frac{\text{d} f(\gamma)}{\text{d}\gamma}(y-\gamma)
$$

Looking at the zeroth order term first, I plug in for $y=\gamma$, and expand the squared and cubed parantheses in the exponent. I get that zeroth order term becomes (the factors outside the integrals cancel)

$$
\frac{e^{-\frac{ k_0 a^2}{2kT}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \gamma e^{-\frac{ k_0 \gamma^2}{2kT}}   e^{ \frac{k_0 a \gamma}{kT}}     e^{-\frac{ k_0 \gamma^4}{2kT}}   e^{\frac{3 k_0 \gamma^3 a}{2kT}}   e^{-\frac{3  k_0 \gamma^2 a}{2kT}}   e^{\frac{ k_0 a^3 \gamma}{2kT}} \text{d} \gamma     }                                         {e^{-\frac{ k_0 a^2}{2kT}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{ k_0 \gamma^2}{2kT}}   e^{\frac{ k_0 a \gamma}{kT}}     e^{-\frac{ k_0 \gamma^4}{2kT}}   e^{\frac{3 k_0 \gamma^3 a}{2kT}}   e^{-\frac{3  k_0 \gamma^2 a}{2kT}}   e^{\frac{ k_0 a^3 \gamma}{2kT}} \text{d}\gamma}
$$

However, I don't know how to proceed to solve this integral. I am not used to doing Taylor expansions, so  may have started off completely wrong, here.

Comment: What is $T$? From your first expression $L(T)= N$.

Comment: An independent variable (temperature), found within $\beta = 1/kT$, where $k$ is the Boltzmann constant.

Comment: I think you do not understand. Your first expression does not depend on $T$, so why $L(T)$? Moreover, the integrals on the numerator and denominator are the same, so that $L(T) = N$. There are other similar inconsistencies, for example,  the approximation of $L(T)$ does not depend on $T$ either. You should edit your question.

Comment: I have added the $T$ dependence to the expressions and fixed the first expression. An error made it in there! So much to keep track of.

Comment: Is $\gamma\le0$? If not, I don't think the integrals in the numerator and denominator converge.

Comment: I forgot to add that $\gamma > 0$. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, my point was that if $\gamma>0$, then $e^{-v(y)/kT} = e^{-\frac{k_0}{2kT}(y-a)^2 + \frac{\gamma}{kT}(y-a)^3}$ which tends to $\infty$ as $y\rightarrow\infty$, thus making the integral diverge. Is $v(y)$ literally a cubic in $y$, or is it just a Taylor approximation? If it is literally a cubic, then I don't know how to make sense of your integrals.